# Why argument @query_result_separator doesn't work

Tags: t-sql

I would like to send en email with attached Excel file using sp_send_dbmail procedure. My desired outcome is that the recipients get the Excel file with separated columns. The procedure works but the problem is that the columns are not separated. Here's my code:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name= 'SQLProfile',
    @recipients='arkadiusz.drezek@cfsa.pl',
    @subject='HLR 1000 - CC Lista', 
    @body='Proteza - do przeksztalcenia z csv -> excel',
    @query ='SELECT * from analizy.dbo.csv',
    @attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
    @query_attachment_filename = 'CSV_Extract.csv',
    @query_result_header = 1,
    @query_result_separator = ';',
    @query_no_truncate = 1
```

Comment: are you sure about using `;`? shouldn't you use `,` as @query_result_separator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to modify your query little bit.

```
@query =' print ''sep=;''; SELECT * from analizy.dbo.csv'

          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

By Printing `sep=;` in csv file as content, this may help to separate the records.